# How do you securely and properly extend the JWT's cookie validity?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, security, jwt

#### The current situation is this and has rather bad UX, but hopefully high security:

The user logs in and gets an access token set as a `HttpOnly` (and secure etc) cookie for let's say an expiration date of `Date.now() + 10min`. There's already a built-in TypeScript/JavaScript timer in the UI, which resets itself back to 10 mins upon scrolling, moving the mouse and similar events, but it has no real functionality/calls to the backend **YET** so it's purely cosmetic. The user keeps using the web app and the set static 10mins since login is the window in which the API calls for the user succeed. Exactly 10mins after login the API calls shall begin returning `403 Forbidden` errors and an error shall be shown on the browser because of expiration checking (`alert('403 Forbidden`);). I tried tampering with the token and the token does not get accepted and due to rewriting rules and etc they get redirected back to the login screen, so it already seems to be secure against any tampering that is not realtime per se. Since the cookie is HttpOnly no JS per XSS and similar attacks can access and steal the cookie. You would need proper malware to steal the cookie/token.

I assume the scenario above sacrifices usability for security, since it's harder to tamper with the JWT this way.

#### From the side of UX I thought this might be the right idea to do the following (please do point out some mistakes if I built any in):

The user logs in and gets an access token set for let's say an expiration date of `Date.now() + 10min`. There's already a built-in TypeScript/JavaScript timer, which resets on scrolling, moving the mouse and similar events and after the timer resets when one of the events trigger when 5 minutes are left or less a request is sent to extend the JWT cookie expiration OR when the user clicks on anything that has backend calls the `extendToken` middleware extends the `exp` epoch time again to 10mins.

Since I'm using express.js I thought using middlewares would be the way to go. That's why I wrote the middleware below, but there might be something I oversaw.

The access token format is the following: `Bearer JWThere` (pretty standard)

##### My experimental middleware for extending the validity looks like the following:

Library used for JWT:
`jsonwebtoken` from NPM which is imported as `jwt2` in the code below.

```
// express.js middleware
function extendToken(req, res, next) {
  var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['Authorization'] || req.cookies.access_token;
  if(token){
    // Split at the space
    const bearer = token.split(' ');
    // Get token from array
    const bearerToken = bearer[1];
    jwt2.verify(bearerToken, 'secret', async function(err, decoded){
     if(err){
       return res.status(403).send({ 
         success: false, 
         message: 'Failed to authenticate.' 
       });
     }else{
      const renewedToken = await jwtSignPromisified({ decoded }, 'secret', { expiresIn: '10min' });
        res.cookie(
            'access_token', 'Bearer ' + renewedToken, {
            // FIXME: In production this should be Strict
            sameSite: 'none',
            path: '/',
            expires: new Date(Date.now() + 600000), // cookie will be removed after 10 mins
            httpOnly: true, // in production also add secure: true (is mandatory now due to sameSite)
            secure: true
        })
            .json(decoded);
       req.decoded = decoded;
       req.lastname = decoded.user.lastname;
       next();
     }
   })
 }else{
   return res.status(403).send({ 
     success: false, 
     message: 'No token provided.' 
   });
 }
}
```

## My questions would be:

- From the side of pure UX, what is better - to somehow use the already implemented frontend timer or just to reset the timer when the user makes backend calls via middleware?
- If you recommend to use the already implemented timer - when and how the backend calls to extend timer should be implemented?
- How do I logically and securely "synchronize" the frontend timer (if that path is recommended) with the backend without making too many unnecessary calls to the backend?
- Is any of the proposed fixes to the UX secure? Would they be secure against JWT tampering again?
- If the previous middleware exposes the decoded JWT with `req.decoded` (with the same logic as in the code snippet) in JSON format is it not smarter to directly take that instead of manually verifying and decoding again?
- Do I need refresh tokens for my use case?

Comment: If your authorization is OAuth2 based, then why not use [one of libraries](https://oauth.net/code/javascript) for that?

Comment: @Justinas Authorization is not done via OAuth2, because there's currently no integration with other services. The authorization and authentication is self-written and has been analyzed by external parties. If I understand OAuth2 correctly that would only make sense if we were to integrate SSO or similar functionality into our web app, right? We do not intend to make a fat client just because we need OAuth2 for a couple of reasons